# Trying to implement mini-http persistent server in C

Tags: c, http

I'm trying to make an http-persistent server with only one connection each time. When I try to set up the server, everything works fine.
The problem comes in the *accept* phase.

The program starts making a demon and waiting for connections with *bind*. That part works perfectly fine until this:

```
    ...declarations...
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;

    tv.tv_sec = 5;      
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    while(1){

        length = sizeof(cli_addr);
        if((socketfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &length)) < 0)
            debug(ERROR,"system call","accept",0);


        int end=0;
        while(!end){

            FD_ZERO(&rfds);
            FD_SET(socketfd,&rfds);

            int is_something = select(socketfd+1,&rfds,NULL,NULL,&tv);


            if(is_something && FD_ISSET(socketfd, &rfds)){
                if((pid = fork()) < 0) debug(ERROR,"system call","fork",0);

                else {
                    if(pid == 0) { 
                        close(listenfd);
                        process_web_request(socketfd); //Let's assume this works fine
                        close(socketfd);
                        exit(1);
                    }           
                }
            }else{
                // We close the connection if timeout comes out
                debug(LOG,"Cierre de conexión","timeout",socketfd);
                (void)close(socketfd);  
                end=1;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I have to wait until there's something in the descriptor with *select* function. My intentions are: if data keeps coming from the socket, I keep reading it and processing (eventually sending HTTP 200 OK and the data), but if in 5 seconds nothing comes from the socket, I close up the connection.

Well. This doesn't work at all. It creates a lot of childs and I don't know why. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you want to fork() outside of the while loop...